# Changing rights and owner in one command to safe resources

Tags: filesystems, ext4, inode, stat, resources

I have a backup script with the following function:

```
function change_rights()
{
    chown -R ${OWNER}:${GROUP} ${DIR}
    find ${DIR} -type f -exec chmod 0640 {} \;
    find ${DIR} -type d -exec chmod 0770 {} \;
}
```

Now the problem is that `${DIR}` is very huge and in order to change the owner and rights I have to traverse the directory at least twice which is extremely resource-intensive.

Is there any way/any command to change the owner **and** rights **at the same time**? That is to say changing what's in the inode in one go?

I'm working on a `ext4` file system.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using find, you could set the necessary shell options to also glob hidden files and have recursive globbing and then do something like

```bsh
for entry in ${DIR}/**/**; do
  chown "${OWNER}:${GROUP}" "${entry}"
  if [[ -d "${entry}" ]] ; then
    # do the thing you do on directories
  else
    # do the thing you do on files
fi
```

but honestly, the overhead of spawing thousands of `chown` processes instead of traversing twice might not be worth it; same for checking whether something is a file in shell logic instead of traversing twice. In the end, you'll have to benchmark this yourself.

I find `find`'s syntax sometimes a bit confusing, but here is what works for me:

```bsh
find  \( -exec /usr/bin/echo ${OWNER}:${GROUP} '{}' \; \) \
-a \( \
      \( -type f -exec /usr/bin/echo 0640 '{}' \; \) \
   -o \( -type d -exec /usr/bin/echo 0770 '{}' \; \) \
   \)
```

Replace `echo` with `chown`/`chmod` as soon as you understand the implications.

Note that the problem here is that you first change the directory permissions before walking into it – that can go wrong, if you can't read and list it yourself afterwards.

> is very huge

If huge is really in the millions of files, then consider using something more tweaked towards that use case than ext4 with standard settings; honestly, even for my collected sources tree, things don't actually take very long.